# JCR query to return excerpt and parent identifier

Tags: xpath, lucene, version, identifier, jcr

I would like to query the jackrabbit repository on the versions I have stored.

My repository looks like the following:

[image: JCR repo structure]

Following xpath query works well:`//element(*, nt:frozenNode)[jcr:contains(., '" + keyword + "') ]/rep:excerpt(.)` and from the Row object returned I can get the excerpt found in the de:template nodes 'de:content' property (for this to be full-text indexable I have my own lucene configuration).

The problem however is: how to know what elements excerpt is found for, since the query only returns me the path found (/jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/95/c8/3e/95c83efc-8441-4017-b3af-ae7be49f07e5/1.0/jcr:frozenNode/de:template) and the excerpt itself.

So I would like to know the **identifier** of the nt:versionHistory node, as stored in Jackrabbit.

I have a solution for this as well, by getting the parent nodes until the nt:versionHistory is reached and getting its identifier:

```
Row row = (Row) rows.next();
Node node = row.getNode();
Node frozenNode = node.getParent();
Node versionNumber = frozenNode.getParent();
String versionId = versionNumber.getIdentifier();
```

However this takes too much time and with lots of versions its bad for the performance.

[image: Profiling JCR Query and getting nodes]

Therefore, I wonder if it's possible to include this version id in the query, such that no parent nodes need to be fetched after the query is executed.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably not possible using an XPath Query. But you could do it using SQL2 using a join:

```
SELECT n.*, excerpt(n), v.[jcr:uuid]
FROM [nt:frozenNode] AS n
INNER JOIN [nt:version] AS v ON ISDESCENDANTNODE(n,v)
WHERE contains(n.*,'Adobe')
```